# Docusign: how to know which signer has signed which of the envelope document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docusignapi

I have an envelope with multiple signers and multiple documents. I need to check who has signed which document at a specific time. Functionnaly, this will allow to throw errors depending on who as signed or not the envelope (Eg. you can't modify that field after sigature of signer2).

I have tried to get the envelope `GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}` ([see doc](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/get/)) but can't see any informations about current signers signature status. Also tried `GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/signature` ([see doc](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/getrecipientsignature/)), but I didn't get any further informations...

How can I check who has currently signed a document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use Connect: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/

This will eliminate your need to poll an endpoint to see who has signed the envelope.